# OpenTok cycleVideo() deteriorates video quality

Tags: javascript, video, opentok, tokbox

I have a problem with switching between front and rear facing camera when streaming with OpenTok (Web version but in mobile browser)

When I click 'switch' icon in my stream player, image quality goes down, and when I switch it again it stays down. I don't see any reason for this in my code as it's really simple:

```
    var switch_btn = document.getElementById("switch-camera");
  switch_btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    publisher.cycleVideo()
   });
```

Is there a better way to do it, or should I just open ticket on their developer page? 
I know that the function returns a promise but that isn't the problem here?

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Could you please email our support team at support@tokbox.com with details and screenshots of what you're seeing?

Comment: Hi, Adam here from TokBox. I think you're running into a bug in the cycleVideo implementation where it does not respect your resolution settings. If you set '1280x720' as the resolution when you create your Publisher and then you call cycleVideo() then when it grabs the new camera it doesn't use those resolution settings anymore. Is this what you're seeing?